# Запятая в ССП во второй части БСП с тире

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, бсп

*Вышел на улицу — пошёл дикий ливень[,] и засверкала молния.*

Действует ли правило, как с двоеточием, когда запятая не ставится, т. к. две части сложносочинённого предложения, соединённых союзом "и", поясняют третью часть, предшествующую им и связанную с ними бессоюзной связью? Тут похожая ситуация, только вместо двоеточия стоит тире, и отношения временные, а не пояснительные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На мой взгляд, не важно, какой стоит знак, — важно, какие отношения он передает. Нет сомнения, что "вышел на улицу" — общий член, поэтому запятая не нужна.

[Знаки препинания между частями бессоюзного предложения:](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_185)
Тире ставится

> если в первом предложении есть значение времени или условия и перед ним можно вставить союз КОГДА или ЕСЛИ, например: Начальство хочет – мы должны повиноваться (Гоголь)

Применительно к данному предложению: 
**Когда я вышел на улицу, пошёл дикий ливень и засверкала молния.**

Answer (score 0):

Выражусь очень аккуратно: мне *кажется*, что в этом предложении запятая перед **и** нужна.

Вот что пишет [Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133).
3) Общей может быть **поясняемая** двумя частями сложносочиненного предложениия третья часть, предшествующая им и связанная с ними бессоюзной связью:
*Берегов не видать* [почему?]: [потому что] *их скрыла ночь и оттолкнули куда-то широкие волны разлива* (М. Г.).

Думаю, что неважно, какой знак используется — двоеточие или тире, — важно, чтобы ССП **поясняло** первое (главное) предложение. В вашем примере таких отношений нет.
Дождь идет, молния сверкает — явления природы не раскрывают причин появления человека на улице, они просто есть, независимо оттого, вышел кто-то за порог или нет.

Запятая, предполагаю, не нужна в таком предложении:
Вышел на улицу — в душной гостиной горели свечи и пылал огонь в камине.

Comment: Так с двоеточием и пояснением я лишь провёл аналогию. У нас то понятно, что отношения не пояснительные, а временные, о чём я, кстати, упомянул.

Comment: Подобное нашему, но СПП: "Когда я вышел на улицу, пошёл дикий ливень и засверкала молния".

Comment: Главное, что есть общий элемент, а его тип не имеет значения.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не нужна:

(1)Вышел на улицу — (2) пошёл дикий ливень и (3) засверкала молния.

Общим элементом предложений с сочинительной связью 2 и 3 является предложение 1 (связь  бессоюзная).

Сравнить: Когда вышел на улицу, пошёл дикий ливень и  засверкала молния.